# Find all the AMIs which do not have an instance associated with it

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, aws-cli

In my aws account, I am having lots of snapshot and ami. I need to find all ami which is not associated instance and need to find all snapshot which is not associated instance.

1. Find all the AMIs which do not have an instance associated with it.
2. Find all the Snapshots which do not have an instance associated with it.

I am not able to find out what is a command between ami and instance...

Please help me....

Comment: Are you trying to use AWS CLI? Why did you tag `ansible`?

Comment: i have tried to use aws cli..but not get much help... if have any idea to make some help with ansible ...i can take.... for creating instacnes,elb,s3,... we use ansible playbook

Comment: Can you please help me in this.. i have tried to find all volumes where states are available. but how can I find which is the snapshot are associated those volumes(available).

Comment: i am not getting any logic to find out all ami .. where instances got terminated or ami are not associated with any instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of AMIs that your EC2 instances were launched from using:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].ImageId"
```

You can get the list of AMIs that you own using:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --query "Images[].ImageId"
```

Add some basic scripting to test if the AMI IDs in the second list are absent from the first list.

Add `--output text` if it helps you parse the results.

Run this in the appropriate regions, by adding `--region <region>`.

Comment: above answer will not help much...i want those ami which is not associated with any instances and snapshots which are also not associated with any instances...

Comment: on github i get very good python scripts.  https://gist.github.com/Eyjafjallajokull/4e917414cfb191391f9e51f6a8c3e46a